# How to see the text of the query in Lithium?

Tags: php, mysql, lithium

This makes me rage from time of cakePHP. How to see the executed SQL query on Model::find()?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here: [Lithium: Can we see queries executed as shown in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314022/lithium-can-we-see-queries-executed-as-shown-in-cakephp).

It's also mentioned in the [Applying Filters: Logging](http://li3.me/docs/book/manual/1.x/common-tasks/filters) section of the docs.